# Why spring-tool-suite-4-4.10.0.RELEASE-e4.19.0-win32.win32.x86_64.self-extracting.jar is Harmful for my Computer

Tags: spring-tool-suite

Why would *spring-tool-suite-4-4.10.0.RELEASE-e4.19.0-win32.win32.x86_64.self-extracting.jar* be *harmful for my computer*? I have downloaded from [here](https://download.springsource.com/release/STS4/4.10.0.RELEASE/dist/e4.19/spring-tool-suite-4-4.10.0.RELEASE-e4.19.0-win32.win32.x86_64.self-extracting.jar).

> This type of file may harm your computer

message appeared.
Please advise me know the correct Link for my Laptop RV509 having installed with Windows10 Pro with 20H2.

Answer (score 0):

The file is not harmful to your computer. This is a generic warning from your computer/OS that you get because the jar is an executable. Anytime you download an executable file onto your computer and execute it you are potentially opening the door for that executable to do 'something bad' (e.g. install a malware).

This warning is so you should be aware of the potential risk before downloading and executing random things from the internet.

The question is really whether you trust the file you downloaded or not. That question is for you to answer.

Note that this risk is somewhat unavoidable. Since you intend to install and run STS on your machine, there is no avoiding running something you downloaded onto your machine.

Simply put, if you do not trust STS to not be a malware, then you shouldn't run it.

So, provided that

- you downloaded the installer from its official website so it is not a 'spoofed' copy, and...
- STS is a product that you trust not to be malware...

... then you can dismiss the warning, elect to keep the file, and run it to install STS onto your computer.